# Kotlin Syntax Question .setOnPreferenceClickListener

Tags: kotlin

I´ve added a SettingsActivity to my app and customized the .xml

Now I want to code, what should happen, when the Preferences get clicked.

So in my `SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat()` I have added the following code and imports.

The part `object : OnPreferenceClickListener` is underlined red and AndroidStudio and me do not know the right solution.

Can anyone tell my the right code/syntax (lamda)?
Language is Kotlin.
Thank you very much and have a great day.

```
import androidx.preference.Preference
import androidx.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener


findPreference<Preference>("logout")?.setOnPreferenceClickListener { object : Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener{
                override fun onPreferenceClick(preference: Preference?): Boolean {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }
            } }
```

Comment: By `AndroidStudio [and me] do not know the right solution.` you mean that when you hit Alt + Enter it doesn't provide you with a quick fix for this warning?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean.

Comment: I deleted the class and created a new in Java. Here everything works fine, thanks to intercompability =))) But still would be interested in the right solution

Answer (score 1):

There was a compilation issue with your code that probably prevented you from getting the IDE to suggest a quick fix, the fix for that would be the following:

```
findPreference<Preference>("logout")?.setOnPreferenceClickListener(object : Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
    override fun onPreferenceClick(preference: Preference?): Boolean {
      TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
})
```

Note the use of `()` around the `object` instead of `{}`. Now you should be able to Alt + Enter on the warning, select "Change to lambda" and the IDE will change the code to the following:

```
findPreference<Preference>("logout")?.setOnPreferenceClickListener { 
  TODO("Not yet implemented") 
}
```